# Is there a portable telnet client for windows that supports ASCII out of the box?

Tags: windows, command-line, portable, telnet

I have tried both PuTTY and DTELNET but the ascii art comes of like this:

[image: dtelnet]

Comment: I don't think you need a different client – you just need to [configure PuTTY properly](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.58/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-termtype) (which would rather be a question for SU).

Comment: Both the clients you mention support ASCII and default to it.

Comment: @SteveBarnes They're *supposed* to, but I still end up with that ^ :(

Comment: @Izzy I can't configure putty from the commandline and that is necessary for the application I am building.

Comment: @RahulBasu - the above is ASCII the problem is your code page does not match the expected.

Comment: @SteveBarnes After I change the encoding, it works.

Comment: @RahulBasu - From & To?

Comment: @RahulBasu what causes this is usually the `TERM` variable not or wrongly set. AFAIK there are ways to configure the default in PuTTY (which usually is set to `xterm`) – and that also applies to the encoding. Again, this "how to" part is a better fit for SU (so please, move the "how to do this with PuTTY" to SU and link to it from your question here. It's of course fine keeping the question for alternatives open here, but the how-to stuff should go there).

Comment: @SteveBarnes from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1